# Can't make div to be a certain width. Something overrides the styling

Tags: html, css

The style i need doesn't even appear in source. I'm trying to make the .widgettext more narrow. No luck so far. I know that urls are not really appreciated here, but I can't copy the whole theme into fiddle. It's obvious that something is overriding the style, and I can't figure out what.

Here is live link
http://soloveich.com/packaging/

Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="infocontainer">

<div class="infowidgets">
  <div class="widgettext">
 #widget
    </div></div>

<div class="infowidgets">
  <div class="widgettext">
  </div></div>

</div>
```

and the css

```
#infocontainer {
width:100%;
min-height: 200px;
background-color: #222222 !important;
z-index: 999999;
}

.infowidgets {
width:50%;
margin-top: 30px !important;
display: inline-block;
float:left;
margin:0;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}


.widgettext {
width: 30%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You have a css style for class .widgettext and in the markup a class .wigettext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply the css style inline like

```
<div class="widgettext" style="width: 30%;margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

then it is the last to be executed and the widget can't overwrite an earlier css style

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in either your HTML or CSS, I'm assuming HTML.

Your HTML has the class as `wigettext` and your CSS has it as `widgettext`

This is why none of the styles you have assigned are applying.

Comment: Despite my answer, I agree, this is most probably the fault if the code is identical

Comment: Yep. noticed it, and corrected one yesterday. That's not it.